# Can I use pre-labeled data in AWS SageMaker Ground Truth NER?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, named-entity-recognition, labeling

Let's say I have some text data that has already been labeled in SageMaker. This data could have either been labeled by humans or an ner model. Then let's say I want to have a human go back over the dataset, either to label new entity class or correct existing labels. How would I set up a labeling job to allow this? I tried using an output manifest from another labeling job, but all of the documents that were already labeled cannot be accessed by workers to re-label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible you are looking for [Custom Labelling worklflows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-custom-templates.html) you can also apply either Majority Voting (MV) or MDS to evaluate the accuracy of the job