# AWS Ground Truth: Label Verification for named entity recognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, named-entity-recognition

I want use AWS Ground Truth to pass pre-labelled **text** to a private workforce to verify existing named entity recognition labels. This is possible for images, see [Image label verification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-label-verification.html), but in this same article it says it is not possible for text: "If you want to create an adjustment or verification labeling job [...] option is only supported for [...] image labeling jobs".

**Question**:
Is there a way to pass a "clever" manifest file that reproduces a named entity recognition label verification job?

Note:
I did try to dig in the link provided in the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587939/can-i-use-pre-labeled-data-in-aws-sagemaker-ground-truth-ner) but I failed to find a suitable tutorial.